# Is it a good practice to have static final field DUMMY in interfaces used as listeners?

Tags: java

Often I have to write classes implementing listener interfaces with empty methods bodies.

For example:

**MyOnClickListener .java**

```
public interface MyOnClickListener {
    void onClick();
}
```

and

**MyDummyOnClickListener .java**

```
public class MyDummyOnClickListener implements MyOnClickListener {
    public void onClick() {
        // skip
    }
}
```

Maybe it would be better to have a `static final` field DUMMY in each such an interface?

**MyOnClickListener .java**

```
public interface MyOnClickListener {
    void onClick();

    public static final MyOnClickListener DUMMY = new MyOnClickListener() {
        public void onClick() {
            // skip
        }
    }
}
```

So I need only **1** `.java` class, and each time when I change interface I don't have to find and open another `.java` class with *"dummy"* implementation.

What do you think? What are the disadvantages of such a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately, it's a bit hard to review code like this because the code you are showing is example code rather than code that you're actually using in a real project, which means that a lot of context has been stripped away. Unlike Stack Overflow, we prefer to look at real code instead of example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern to avoid these instances is to create a 'default' abstract class for the interface. One that comes to mind is the [SAX parser's DefaultHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html)

Consider an abstract class (marked abstract even though it implements the method):

```
public abstract class DefaultOnClickListener implements MyOnClickListener {
    public void onClick() {
        // override to implement
    }
}
```

Now, you can extend the class, and chose to change the behaviour, by overriding the method, or leaving the default behaviour, by not overriding the method.

This solution means that the dummy implementations are only in one place.

Comment: I don't really see the advantage of marking it abstract...? What if I just wanted the empty/default listener?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - marking it abstract means you cannot simply create an instance, you have to create either an anonymous or concrete implementation. This is a low-priority thing, making it a concrete class would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Disadvantages are:

- you lose readability of the code
- a bug in the dummy listener (you can't always do **nothing**) might require updates to an otherwise stable package
- not sure what the problem is with having **2** java files. Any decent IDE makes it a breeze to manage them.
- everyone will see DUMMY in autocomplete :(

So no, there are no solid **should never do this** arguments but I don't see why you would ever do that given that you lose nothing with two files.

Perhaps the bigger question is: why do you have dummy implementations? In some cases I provide a "Simple" (actually functioning implementation) or a "Base" (abstract base class that handles stupid stuff) implementation, but never an empty one.

Mocking tools take care of it for testing and in actual code it would be odd to need completely empty implementations.